Refresh default bash terminal when Codespace container starts
This is a small QoL thing but I have a postCreateCommand.sh script that installs bash-completion so my git autocomplete works. It works well but the default bash terminal that Codespaces presents me with does not work with autocomplete. I have to open a new terminal to use autocomplete.
Is there anyway to get this first terminal I am presented with to make use of bash-completion?
postCreateCommand.sh
#!/bin/bash

# Check if running as root
if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "This script must be run as root"
    exit 1
fi

# Install npm packages
npm install
npm audit fix

# Update apt package manager and install bash-completion
apt update
apt install -y bash-completion

devcontainer.json
"postCreateCommand": "sudo bash .devcontainer/postCreateCommand.sh"


You most likely need to source something when installation completes. But without any code, it's hard to help you.

I have added the relevant files.
